# product export error : Unsupported operand type

Tags: error

How can I solve this :

> Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\wamp\www\abc\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\Model\Export\Entity\Product.php
>   on line 875

It occurs when trying to export products via the admin panel `system -> import/export` menu.

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: my current php version 5.5.12

Comment: scrap my answer then...:)  What version of Magento is it?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: that line does stand out as being different to all the others in that function so have posted an answer I think will work as a fix.

Comment: cool beans. If it is a working answer please mark it as so :) Glad it helped.  There was a similar problem in the admin following one of the updates earlier in the year too.

Comment: ok,  appreciate your response.

Answer (score 10):

Magento have a patch for this issue as SUPEE-6511.

Ask magento support for the official patch file, however the change provided is simple enough. Around line 875-ish in `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php` you should update as follows.

```
-    $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
+    if (isset($stockItemRows[$productId])) {
+        $dataRow = array_merge($dataRow, $stockItemRows[$productId]);
+    }
```

Comment: Where can we find the official patch file for SUPEE-6511?  We are having the same issue on CE 1.9.2.4 which doesn't offer Magento support.  However, I would prefer to have the official patch on file if there is one.

Comment: No official patch on hand sorry. Magento only generally hand out security patches. The only other source of patches would be https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/

Comment: Fix mentioned here is correct, but issue still exists in 1.9.3.7 https://github.com/firegento/magento/blob/4d15f15875424e338daf6836f30f56f8f1788dc8/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php#L948

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that it worked from my end using Magento 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the rest of the $dataRow manipulations that line does look odd.

Try replacing

```
875:    $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```

with

```
$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);
```

However, directly modifying core files is bad so you should override it but a quick test should show if it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the problem line (as you didn't specify your Magento version) looks something like this:

```
875:    $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```

My first thing to check would be the version of php you are using.  I do not think that, for pre PHP v5.2 (and some of v5.2...), the += operand is not supported for arrays, which this action is.

Answer (score 1):

This worked great: `$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);`

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly work for me. Thanks.

```
$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);
```

Comment: @ Chirag Parmar : could you pls join chat room

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46279/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-113044-product-export-error-unsupporte